# Как вернуть в логине sddm курсор в окно ввода пароля?

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

Manjaro KDE Edition 64x версий 17.0.1, 17.0.2-pre4.
Десктоп на mITX на Asus P8H61-I rev3.0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемы две:

1) искажение геометрии на двухмониторной системе. Да, я знаю, у меня разные разрешения экранов, но как заставить sddm не растягивать картинку и отображать её корректно на широкоформатном экране? 
Поправил разрешение и номера экранов в /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup 
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 60.02 --output VGA1 --mode 1680x1050 --rate 60.02

Не помогло.

2) Экран графической аутентификации пользователя (sddm) не имеет фокуса на окне ввода пароля, и ввести пароль можно только кликнув на поле ввода мышью. Никакие курсоры и табуляции не помогают. Я пробовал выключать и включать службу sddm, переустанавливать, но это не помогло.

Прошу совета!